# Read from txt file to matrix after a specific expression

Tags: file, matlab

I wanted via matlab to read a table of data from a txt file after a specific expression and a number of non desired lines for example the `AA.txt` have:

Information about students :

```
AAAA

BBBB

1 10 100

2  3  15
```

*!  !   !       a number of lines*

```
10  6   9
```

I have like information the expression 'Information about students', the number of skipped lines 2 and the number of columns 3 and rows 10 in desired matrix.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you wanna skip the first 3 lines (assuming them as headers) and then reading the rest.

I would follow this procedure:

```
fid = fopen(filename,'r');
A = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f','HeaderLines',3,'Delimiter','\r\n');
```

I currently do not have access to `MATLAB`, but I do believe it will work.

Comment: Tanks fpe, the idea is to localize the 'Information about students' expression and count 2 header line and star reading a matrix with 3 colones and 10 rows.